# multi select tree inside drop down box (with the ability to select headers not elements only)

Tags: jquery, css

[here the code I'm using](http://www.megafileupload.com/a6rr/jquery-multiselect-tree*.zip)

and this the html page

can anyone help me either by how to make the same thing in a drop down box or put this cod inside drop down box? I'm new in jQuery so if there is a way by using it or using CSS I don't mind at all.

[a picture of what the result of this code will looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMf4c.png)

```
<head>
<title>AKC Breed List</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/global.css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
<div class="canine row">
<h3>Filter by Group or Breed</h3>
<ul class="span4">
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="all" name="check-all" /> All Breeds </li>
    <li class="parent-list"><input type="checkbox" name="" id="" class="canine parent" /> Sporting Group <i class="icon-caret-down"></i>
        <ul>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> American Water Spaniel </li>
            <li class="parent-list"><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine parent" id="" /> Brittany <i class="icon-caret-down"></i>
                <ul>
                <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> test1 </li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> test2 </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Chesapeake Bay Retriever </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Cocker Spaniel </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> English Setter </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> German Shorthaired Pointer </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Golden Retriever </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Labrador Retriever </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Vizsla </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Weimaraner </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Welsh Springer Spaniel </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="parent-list"><input type="checkbox" name="" id="" class="canine parent" /> Hound Group <i class="icon-caret-down"></i>
        <ul>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Afghan Hound </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> American English Coonhound </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> American Foxhound </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Basenji </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Bloodhound </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Dachshund </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> English Foxhound </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Greyhound </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Rhodesian Ridgeback </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Whippet </li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="parent-list"><input type="checkbox" name="" id="" class="canine parent" /> Working Group <i class="icon-caret-down"></i>
        <ul>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Akita </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Alaskan Malamute </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Bernese Mountain Dog </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Boxer </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Bullmastiff </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Cane Corso </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Doberman Pinscher </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> German Pinscher </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Great Dane </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Great Pyrenees </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Great Swiss Mountain Dog </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Komondor </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Kuvasz </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Mastiff </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Newfoundland </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Rottweiler </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Saint Bernard </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Siberian Husky </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Tibetan Mastiff </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="parent-list"><input type="checkbox" name="" id="" class="canine parent" /> Toy Group <i class="icon-caret-down"></i>
        <ul>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Affenpinscher </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Brussels Griffon </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Cavalier King Charles Spaniel </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Chihuahua </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Chinese Crested </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> English Toy Spaniel </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Havanese </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Italian Greyhound </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Japanese Chin </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Maltese </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Manchester Terrier </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Miniature Pinscher </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Papillon </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Pekingese </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Pomeranian </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Pug </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Shih Tzu </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Silky Terrier </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Toy Fox Terrier </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Yorkshire Terrier </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="parent-list"><input type="checkbox" name="" id="" class="canine parent" /> Non-Sporting Group <i class="icon-caret-down"></i>
        <ul>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> American Eskimo Dog </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Bichon Frise </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Boston Terrier </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Bulldog </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Chinese Shar-Pei </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Chow Chow </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Dalmatian </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Finnish Spitz </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> French Bulldog </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Keeshond </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Lhasa Apso </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> L&#246;wchen </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Norwegian Lundehund </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Poodle </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Schipperke </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Shiba Inu </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Shih Tzu </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Tibetan Spaniel </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Tibetan Terrier </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Xoloitzcuintli </li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="parent-list"><input type="checkbox" name="" id="" class="canine parent" /> Terrier Group <i class="icon-caret-down"></i>
        <ul>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> American Water Spaniel </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Brittany </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Chesapeake Bay Retriever </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Cocker Spaniel </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> English Setter </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> German Shorthaired Pointer </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Golden Retriever </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Labrador Retriever </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Vizsla </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Weimaraner </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Welsh Springer Spaniel </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="parent-list"><input type="checkbox" name="" id="" class="canine parent" /> Herding Group <i class="icon-caret-down"></i>
        <ul>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Australian Cattle Dog</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Australian Shepherd </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Bearded Collie </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Beauceron</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Belgian Malinois </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Belgian Sheepdog </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Belgian Tervuren </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Border Collie </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Bouvier des Flandres </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Briard </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Canaan Dog </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Cardigan Welsh Corgi</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Collie </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Entlebucher Mountain Dog </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Finnish Lapphund</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> German Shepherd Dog </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Icelandic Sheepdog </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Norwegian Buhund </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Old English Sheepdog  </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Pembroke Welsh Corgi </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Polish Lowland Sheepdog</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Puli </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Pyrenean Shepherd </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Shetland Sheepdog</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Swedish Vallhund </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="parent-list"><input type="checkbox" name="" id="" class="canine parent" /> Miscellaneous Class <i class="icon-caret-down"></i>
        <ul>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Azawakh</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Belgian Laekenois </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Bergamasco</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Berger Picard</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Boerboel </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Cirneco dell’Etna</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Coton de Tulear </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Dogo Argentino </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Lagotto Romagnolo </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Miniature American Shepherd </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Peruvian Inca Orchid </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Pumi</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Sloughi </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Spanish Water Dog </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="" class="canine" id="" /> Wirehaired Vizsla</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi there, please don't link to offsite code. Instead, paste the **relevant** code in here and make sure you format it by prepending four spaces or a tab character to each line of code.

Comment: sorry but because it's a folder that contains CSS files, fonts, js and the html page.

Comment: The reason I'm saying this is that no-one wants to download anything to answer a question as it could contain something malicious. (And also because we don't need the CSS files and fonts to see what you are trying to do.) If you want, you could try to create a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or equivalent.

Comment: you are right. I added the code to my question now.